# How to prove equality between two sets contained in union of another two disjoint sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need help completing the following proof:

Let $A,B$ be two **disjoint** sets, and $X,Y\subseteq A\cup B$.
I want to prove that if $X\setminus A=Y\setminus A$ and $X\setminus B=Y\setminus B$ then $X=Y$.

So suppose $X\setminus A=Y\setminus A$, and let's prove $X=Y$.
Let $x\in X$. Since $X\subseteq A\cup B$, it holds that $x\in A \vee x\in B$.

Now two cases are possible:

Case 1: Suppose $x\notin A$. This means $x\in X \wedge x\notin A$ so $x\in X\setminus A$, according to the given premise, we get $x\in Y\setminus A$, so $x\in Y\wedge x\notin A$ and we conclude $x\in Y$.

Case 2: Suppose $x\in A$...
This is where I'm stuck... I can't use the given premise that $X\setminus A=Y\setminus A$, how can I proceed?
Also, I understand why it is necessary for $A$ and $B$ to be disjoint in order for this to be true, and I can easily find a counter example in this case, but where in the proof am I using  the fact that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint? How does that help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something is missing. Take $X=A$ and $Y=B$ (both non-empty), then $X\setminus A=\varnothing=Y\setminus B$, but $A\neq B$.

Comment: We also necessarily have $C = X \backslash A \subset B$ and $D = Y \backslash B \subset A$ so that $C,D$ cannot be equal *unless* they are both empty.

Comment: Sorry for the mix up! I edited my post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $x \in X$. We want to show it is in $Y$. By assumption, $x \in A$ or $x \in B$.

If $x \in A$, then $x\in X \backslash B$ (since $A$ and $B$ are disjoint), and further $X \backslash B = Y \backslash B$, so $x \in Y$.

You can argue the other cases similarly.

Comment: Thank you! this was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* $X = (X \setminus A) \cup (X \setminus B), Y = (Y \setminus A) \cup (Y \setminus B).$